# Remover WWW e HTTP / HTTPS com expressão regular

Tags: regex

Olá, estou fazendo um script que insere valores dentro de um sistema de finanças, porem quando insere com o 'www' 'http' 'https' dá erro e eu tenho que remover na mão. Por isso quero colocar uma expressão regular que remove esses valores da url antes de enviar. O script ja esta enviando, so gostaria de ajuda para formar a expressão regular.

Comment: Isso depende da linguagem em uso, cada uma tem sua forma de fazer o replace. Para tal  só é necessário dar um match em "www|https?' e subtituir por nada

Comment: Qual linguagem de backend?

Comment: eu to criando o script com JS. Então uso o .replace(***)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para realizar a remoção do www, http e https é necessário utilizar o replace da seguinte forma:

```
string.replace( /www|https?/ , '');
```

O `?` indica que o **s** é opcional podendo existir ou não e caso exista será substituido.

O `|` é a condicional **ou**

Comment: Sua resposta supriu a necessidade, porem eu dei uma melhorada para abranger mais opções de sites pois o usuário sempre surpreende, ficou assim: .replace(/h?t?t?p?s?\:?\/\/w?w?w?.?|www./ , '')

Comment: @LeticiaFatima, se a idéia for remover o protocolo e o "www", vale a pena dar uma olhada nessa outra aqui:  https://regex101.com/r/Bj4RwO/2

Comment: Carlosn, esse ficou perfeito!!